# Where to store Registry data for All Users

Tags: windows, registry, uac

I would like to share a small amount of data between All Users in the Windows Registry. For shared read **and write** access between any user that logs into the machine or a service on the machine. Is there a location where this can be done? I have tried using "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\" but this seems to be blocked by the Vista UAC rules.

Answer (score 6):

You can put all users data in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` hive, but you'll need to adjust the permissions on the key to in order to make it writable by all users, as your question states.

Answer (score 4):

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` should be the place to store data between users. There's a good, short explanation [here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vista/vista_registry_structure.htm) about which folders/hives are used for what.

Comment: That's going to be blocked by UAC, in my experience.
I asked this question before (I was trying to find MY question when I saw yours <g>). 
I have not found any location that ALL users can write/read to without Admin privileges.

Comment: If you relax the privileges on the key that you add under HKLM\Software, that'll give you the location that you need without UAC interfering. Short of going back to using .INI files (which, apparently, Microsoft is advocating these days), I don't see any other choice.

Comment: I have found that when I need a value that contains data shared between users I use the local machine hive to create an appropriate key for my application. I then create a sub-key that contains user modifiable values and set the permissions during the installation on that key to allow the user to write to it. Other values that only the administrator should change are placed outside this sub-key.